# Regular expression to allow backslash in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone provide me with regex for validating string which only should not allow any special characters except backslash. I tried

```
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\ ]*$");
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" means? What does it do that you don't expect?

Answer (score 28):

Backslashes need to be escaped in regular expressions - and they *also* need to be escaped in C#, unless you use [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx). So either of these should work:

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\ ]*$");
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\ ]*$");
```

Both of these ensure that the following string content is passed to the `Regex` constructor:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\\ ]*$
```

The `Regex` code will then see the double backslash and treat it as "I really want to match the backslash character."

Basically, you always need to distinguish between "the string contents you want to pass to the regex engine" and "the string literal representation in the source code". (This is true not just for regular expressions, of course. The debugger doesn't help by escaping in Watch windows etc.)

EDIT: Now that the question has been edited to show that you originally had *three* backslashes, that's just not valid C#. I *suspect* you were aiming for "a string with three backslashes in" which would be either of these:

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\ ]*$");
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\\\ ]*$");
```

... but you don't need to escape the space as far as the regular expression is concerned.

Comment: Please note that nothing is passed to the Regex ctor, because the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The code that *showed* in the question compiled before you edited it. (When I answered the question, the question showed two backslashes. Not in code style, and I understand that the markdown had three backslashes, but I was answering the question I saw :)

Comment: I merely formatted the code. Please have a look at the source of the original revision. The three backslashes were there from the beginning.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth For some reason the question looked like it had only two backslashes in the beginning. The third one only showed up correctly when you formatted it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yes, I was editing my comment. They were present in the markdown, but I was answering the question as displayed :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Alright. You might think about adjusting your answer to what is displayed now :)

Answer (score 11):

You either need to double escape it (once for C# and once for the Regex engine):

```
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\ ]*$");
```

Or you can use the [verbatim string feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) of C# (note the @):

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\ ]*$");
```

In a verbatim string, the backslash is not interpreted as starting an escape sequence, so you just need to escape it once for the Regex engine.

I assume that your current code doesn't compile. It should say something along the lines of "Unrecognized escape sequence".
The reason for this is that you have three backslashes followed by a space. The first two backslashes are interpreted as an escape sequence representing a backslash, but the third backslash is interpreted as starting an escape sequence with a space as the second character. Such an escape sequence doesn't exist, leading to the error.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to escape the `\` for regex as well as C# string by adding **4** `\s` for matching a single `\`.