# Regex - Escape character

Tags: .net, regex

I have this regex: `(?:\[|\G(?!^))('[^']+?')\s*,?\s*(?=[^\]]*?\])` which matches only content between quotes inside square brackets (like an array): ['Foo', 'Bar'] => returns `'Foo' 'Bar'`.

The problem is that in this case the single quote is an special character, since it's used by the regex as a delimiter, but it's necessary for me to pass sometimes the single quote inside the value as a escaped character: `['F'oo', 'B'ar']`.

I'm trying to do something like 'F\'oo', by adapting this non-capturing `(?:(?=(\\?))\1.)` group to the regex, but it doesn't work, I tried many different ways.

This non-capturing group regex comes from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171499/4343335), where the he successfully uses the backslash to escape special characters.

I use C# with .NET Core.

The full text is something like: `eq('Property', ['F'oo', 'Ba'r', '123'])`

How can this be solved?

Comment: Can't just use `'.+?'` to wash out delimiters, doesn't work that way. Petrod's `['F'o''o',',',',',',','ar'].`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use

```
(?:\[|\G(?!\A))
('.+?')
(?:(?:\s*,\s*)|\])
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/69xP9V/1/).

Comment: Excelent solution! Not only you kept the basic premise that was only match items inside the square brackets, you went one step further and gave a solution that spared the use of the backslash to escape the quote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [similar question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes) for getting quoted escaped characters. I'd prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/5527985).

Change your capturing part `('[^']+?')` to [`('[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*')`](https://regex101.com/r/fCxqVc/1). You can further drop the lazy quantifier which won't make much difference when using a negated class already.

It might be necessary to do additional [escaping of the backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641374/5527985).

Comment: Your solution is great! Does exactly what I asked! The only thing that differed from the accepted answer is the need for the backslash. Thank you!

Comment: @MurariAlex Thanks :) Yes that's how I understood the question. To deal with backslash escaped single quotes inside the single quoted string. Good you found a solution that fits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe,

```
(?<=\[|,)\s*'(.*?)'\s*(?=\]|,)
```

or some expression similar to that might work OK.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcZcXs/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=\[|,)\s*'(.*?)'\s*(?=\]|,)";
        string input = @"['Foo', 'Bar']
['F'oo', 'B'ar']
['F'oo', 'B'ar','Foo', 'Bar']";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is some excellent solution too! The only thing that is missing that I needed is to only match the elements when the square brackets are present (in the full text), so I can enforce syntax. Other than that, you nailed it! Thank you!